# Creating single texture for all materials in substance painter with ID map. ID map doesn't bake properly

Tags: textures, blender, 3d-meshes, 3d-modeling, asset-creation

I am trying to create single texture for multiple materials in substance painter according to this tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HMP2xpGHimY

I have two models made in Blender. One with several materials(for generating ID map), another with one material.

Mesh for ID map:

[image]

Main mesh:

[image]

Both are totally identical from geometry and scale standpoint.

Generating ID map settings(it is a mobile game so I use only Unlit texture and don't require other maps and channels except for BaseColor):

[image]

Painting the model with masks created with ID map and actual problem.

[image]
[image]

Id map:
[image]

Model's materials in Blender (everything is great here):
[image]

How can I handle this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used unwrap on both meshes instead of Smart UV Project and have them reimported.  It helped.

[image]

I believe it was some UV issue.